# Reload Image with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, reload

I have the following jquery code :

```js
function ajax_set_thumbnail(item_id, full_path)
{
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = 'full_path=' + full_path;
  xhttp.open("POST", "/ajax/set_thumbnail/" + item_id + "/", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhttp.send(params);

  var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  $('#thumbnail').attr('src', $('#thumbnail').attr('src') + '?' + timestamp )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My goal is to update a thumbnail then to reload the new thumbnail (same name just the picture change).

The code works, but not as I would like to.
I want to update the picture and then to reload it.
But when I checked the trace, the reload comes before the update is done.
So I have no change on the image.

How could I do ?

Comment: If you're using jquery, consider using `$.ajax` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  If you're not using ajax then consider using `fetch()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API  Both should be easier than manually configuring XMLHttpRequest.   (and all 3 have the same issue in that they are *A*jax so your subsequent code will run before they have finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert but if the image reload happens before the AJAX request to update the picture is completed, you should use the `onreadystatechange` event of the `XMLHttpRequest` object. This event is triggered every time the ready state of the `XMLHttpRequest` changes. By checking if the request is completed and successful (readyState 4 and status 200), you can ensure that the code to reload the image is executed only after the picture has been updated on the server.

Here's how you can modify your `ajax_set_thumbnail` function to achieve this:

```js
function ajax_set_thumbnail(item_id, full_path) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = 'full_path=' + encodeURIComponent(full_path);
  xhttp.open("POST", "/ajax/set_thumbnail/" + item_id + "/", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  // Use onreadystatechange to detect when the AJAX request is complete
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Check if the request is complete and was successful
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // This code will run after the thumbnail has been updated on the server
      
      // Append a timestamp query parameter to the image src to force the browser to reload it
      var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
      $('#thumbnail').attr('src', function() {
        // Remove any existing timestamp query parameter before adding the new one
        var src = $(this).attr('src').split('?')[0];
        return src + '?' + timestamp;
      });
    }
  };

  // Send the AJAX request
  xhttp.send(params);
}
```

This modified version of your function waits for the AJAX request to successfully complete before proceeding to update the image's `src` attribute to force a reload. It also ensures that any existing query parameters are removed from the image's `src` before appending the new timestamp. This is done by splitting the `src` string at the `?` character and only using the first part (the original URL without query parameters) before appending the new timestamp query parameter.

This code does not include error handling.

Comment: You're maybe not an expert but it solved my problem.
Thanks  lot, I understand the idea and try to find a way but didn't successed ;)